# Can't get service file working in Angular 4 Plunkr

Tags: angular, plunker

I'm trying to create a plunkr so I can ask you guys a question and when I add the service file to the main app component I get this error

> zone.js:392 Error: (SystemJS) Error: Can't resolve all parameters for QuestionService: (?).

here's the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/nBpriDOgC88Fo2WMpM6A?p=preview

I used the `Angular` option from the `New` menu to create the base and one thing that struck me as odd was the "app.component" is just `src/app.ts` with no `.component` on it.  I also ran into an issue getting the template file to load because instead of `templateUrl: './app.html`,`and adding`moduleId: module.id,`to the component I got the url to work with`templateUrl: 'src/app.html'`without the`moduleId` which for some reason caused errors.

I made a duplicate of `app.service.ts` as `app-service.ts` and linked that in and got the same error.  I tried changing/deleting one letter from the import, path and providers just to see what types of errors it threw and it seems that by simply adding it to the providers it can't be resolved.  I even deleted it from the `constructor` to see if that was far back enough to stop the issue.  I tinkered with the path to the `JSON` file adding `src/` to the path and nothing seemed to make any difference.  I'm running `Angular 2` on my computer so I don't understand what it is I'm missing here.  So far from what I've come across pretty much anything we can do in Angular 2 is supported in Angular 4.  I've checked over the file names to make sure I have `src/` in from of them and not `scr/`, can someone help shed light on what I'm missing here?

Comment: Change `HTTP` to `Http` https://plnkr.co/edit/CXdgAqLu9XF7AS91Y5Y9?p=preview

Comment: wonder how I didn't see that lol